# jQuery mobile scroll momentum

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am writing a jQuery scroll plugin to use in a phonegap android project, It works fine on phonegap but I want to add native like scroll momentum without using any extra plugin.

Can someone help me to add momentum to this plugin.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.touchScroll = function() {
        var scrollContainer = this;
        var scrollContent = this.children();
        var yTravelled = 0, prevY, touch, position, scroll = 0, scrollDown = true, scrollUp = true;
        var mY = scrollContainer.height()/2;

        scrollContainer.on({
            touchmove : function(e) {
                position = scrollContent.position().top;
                touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0] || e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];
                    if (touch.pageY < mY) {
                        if(scrollDown){
                            prevY && (yTravelled -= Math.abs(touch.pageY - prevY));
                            prevY = touch.pageY;
                            mY = touch.pageY;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if(scrollUp){
                            prevY && (yTravelled += Math.abs(touch.pageY - prevY));
                            prevY = touch.pageY;
                            mY = touch.pageY;
                        }
                    }

                scrollContent.css({"transform":"translate3d(0,"+(scroll+yTravelled)+"px,0)"});
                var scrollContentHeight = scrollContent.height();
                var windowHeight = scrollContainer.height();
                var scrollEnd = (scroll+yTravelled) - scrollContainer.height();

                if(Math.abs(scrollEnd) > scrollContentHeight){
                    !scrollDown;
                    scrollContent.css({"transform":"translate3d(0,-"+(scrollContentHeight - windowHeight)+"px,0)"});
                }else scrollDown;

                if(scroll+yTravelled > 0){
                    !scrollUp;
                    scrollContent.css({"transform":"translate3d(0,0,0)"});
                }else{
                    scrollUp;
                }

            },
            touchend : function() {
                scroll = position;
                prevY = 0;
                yTravelled = 0;                     
            }
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

This is a working example of plugin.

https://jsfiddle.net/nicolagrosu/eaeq1gys/4/

Comment: SO is probably not the right place, to ask for help developing a plug-in.

Comment: I don't want anyone to help developing this plugin. Simply i just want some guidance about how i can add native like scrolling momentum to this plugin.